# OSGI bundle is not getting started in Apache Servicemix

Tags: osgi, httpclient, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, apache-servicemix

I am developing http client application as a OSGI bundle project, i have used apache maven to create project folder structure used below command.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.karaf.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=karaf-blueprint-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.3.7 -DgroupId=com.techiyhub -DartifactId=integration.sms -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=com.techiyhub.integration.sms
```

The above command created project folder structure, as i am using httpclient based application. i have added dependencies in pom.xml as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"><modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.techiyhub</groupId>
<artifactId>integration.sms</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>integration.sms Blueprint Bundle</name>
<description>integration.sms OSGi blueprint bundle project.</description>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.techiyhub.integration.sms*;version=${project.version}
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I executed below command,

mvn install

it created desired jar file in local maven repository.

Problem started here. i tried to deploy the bundle in apache servicemix it has installed the bundle but while starting bundle it gave an error

i have executed below commands in servicemix shell

osgi:install mvn:com.techiyhub/integration.sms/1.0-SNAPSHOT

it got installed with bundle id, then i executed below command

osgi:start 302

It gave below error

> Error executing command: Error starting bundles:
>           Unable to start bundle 302: Unresolved constraint in bundle integration.sms [302]: Unable to resolve 302.0: miss
>   ing requirement [302.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http)

Full error stack trace as below

> 

```
2015-10-26 14:33:12,551 | ERROR | l Console Thread | Console                          | 22 - org.apache.karaf.shell.cons
ole - 2.4.3 | Exception caught while executing command
org.apache.karaf.shell.console.MultiException: Error starting bundles:
        Unable to start bundle 302: Unresolved constraint in bundle integration.sms [302]: Unable to resolve 302.0: miss
ing requirement [302.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.MultiException.throwIf(MultiException.java:91)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.StartBundle.doExecute(StartBundle.java:43)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:37)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:38)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_80]
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler$1.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:54)[16:org.apache.aries.proxy.impl:1.0.4]

        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:119)[16:org.apache.aries.proxy.impl:1.0.4]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.commands.$BlueprintCommand22803378.execute(Unknown Source)[22:org.apache.karaf
.shell.console:2.4.3]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[22:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.
4.3]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)[22:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.3]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403)[22:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.
4.3]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[22:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.3]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)[22:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.3]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)[22:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.3]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:92)[22:org.apache.karaf.shel
l.console:2.4.3]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:195)[22:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.3]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.DelayedStarted.run(DelayedStarted.java:79)[22:org.apache.karaf.shell.con
sole:2.4.3]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to start bundle 302: Unresolved constraint in bundle integration.sms [302]: Unabl
e to resolve 302.0: missing requirement [302.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.StartBundle.doExecute(StartBundle.java:39)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle integration.sms [302]: Unable to resolve
302.0: missing requirement [302.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4002)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:963)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.StartBundle.doExecute(StartBundle.java:37)
        ... 18 more


        Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle : Unable to resolve: missing requirement [302.0] osgi.wiring.package;(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http)
```

Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a bundle the maven bundle plugin scans the class files of your project for all used packages. It creates Import-Package statements for these in the Manifest.

Then at runtime you have to make sure you also install all necessary libraries you need to run your bundle. The error message helps you in finding the correct bundles to install. So in your case you have to install a bundle that exports the package org.apache.http.

In your case these are:

```
mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore-osgi/4.3.3
mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.3.6
```

Comment: Thank  you @Christain Schneider for solution with detailed explanation, it helped me to learn. The problem got fixed with your solution. i am curious to know about finding correct libraries, that you said "The error message helps you in finding the correct bundles to install", where it is mentioned in error message.

Comment: OSGi tells you which package in which version range is missing. Unfortunately you then have to find a matching bundle on your own. In many cases the original projects already produce bundles like in the case above. In other cases the servicemix bundles subproject can help. I typically search on maven central using the package name.

Comment: Thank you @Christian Schneider